# Направить в pipe уже запущенный процесс

Tags: shell, pipes

Например, я запустил какой-то процесс, который работает и выдаёт довольно много текста в stdout. Я понимаю, что весь поток текста читать не успею, но знаю, как отфильтровать нужое мне.

Можно ли уже запущенный процесс из stdout перенаправить, например в `| grep somefilter` или `| less`? Как это сделать?

(Понятно, что можно остановить и перезапустить, но в некоторых случаях это неприемлемо.)

Comment: [Так](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1323999/4041128) пойдет? Т.е. перенаправляем в файл, а потом tailf по нему и делаем что надо. Может можно и сразу засунуть команды, но с этим не ко мне )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin

Comment: @user1034749 спасибо, завтра опробую, сегодня не успел.

Answer (score 1):

перевод ответа [Redirect STDERR / STDOUT of a process AFTER it's been started, using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593764/4827341):

- подключитесь к процессу программой *gdb* и выполните в ней команды (`/dev/null` здесь в качестве примера; подставьте имя реального файла):

  - p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 1)
  - p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 2)
  - detach
  - quit

пример:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/lastlog &
[1] 5636

$ ls -l /proc/5636/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 3 -> /var/log/lastlog

$ gdb -p 5636
GNU gdb 6.8-debian
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Attaching to process 5636
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/tail...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/librt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7f3c8f5a66e0 (LWP 5636)]
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

(no debugging symbols found)
0x00007f3c8eec7b50 in nanosleep () from /lib/libc.so.6

(gdb) p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),1)
[Switching to Thread 0x7f3c8f5a66e0 (LWP 5636)]
$1 = 1

(gdb) p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),2)
$2 = 2

(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /usr/bin/tail, process 5636

(gdb) quit

$ ls -l /proc/5636/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 3 -> /var/log/lastlog
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 4 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 5 -> /dev/null
```

Comment: Круто! А вместо `/dev/null` можно  посоветовать открывать fifo с предварительно подключенной к нему в фоне командой (например, `grep`)